# Can I reference Storyboard resources in XAML defind Visual States?

Tags: silverlight, storyboard, visualstatemanager

I have six different objects with their own Visual State Managers. The Focused state of each object is the same. I want to define a single Focused State Storyboard resource and reference it in each of the 6 Focus Visual states. Can this be done?  Here's my code (all in the same UserControl.Resources):

```
<Storyboard x:Key="FocusedState">
     ...
</Storyboard>
```

In each of my 6 objects I have the following:

```
<VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
 <VisualState x:Name="Focused" Storyboard="{StaticResource FocusedState}"/>
...
```

When I run the project I get the following error:

Message: Attribute {StaticResource FocusedState} value is out of range.

Comment: I do not think that Storyboards are shareable.

Comment: Not shareable in what sense? I know I can create a storyboard as I've done and use it via c# as many times and places as I like. The question really is whether VisualStates can reference resources. Visual Studio seems to think so, as I didn't get a compile/parse error with the above syntax.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's not possible to use dynamic resource reference or binding to set Storyboard or Animation values in control templates. I found the answer and explanation on this [post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-SG/wpf/thread/1b2bb84d-58c6-4dde-9c6c-00ed466e2382).